# "Unfortunately,Project has stopped" in android

Tags: android

this is my New.java i have a button on this xml  which redirects to another display xml by using Display.java but i am encountering the error:

Unfortunately,Project has stopped

> New.java

```
package com.example.pallavi.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;


public class New extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onbuttonClick(View v){

        if(v.getId()==R.id.Bdisplay)
        {

            Intent i= new Intent(New.this,Display.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> Display.java:

```
package com.example.pallavi.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by pallavi on 11/5/15.
 */
public class Display extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
    }


}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml:

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pallavi.project" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".New"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Display">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>][1]
```

my logcat:

```
05-11 15:31:27.548    2130-2139/com.android.calendar W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-11 15:31:29.104    1218-1236/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{316ced65 u0 com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackService}
05-11 15:31:29.849    2130-2273/com.android.calendar I/GlobalDismissManager﹕ no sender configured
05-11 15:31:29.849    2130-2273/com.android.calendar D/AlertService﹕ Beginning updateAlertNotification
05-11 15:31:29.854    2130-2273/com.android.calendar D/AlertService﹕ No fired or scheduled alerts
05-11 15:31:29.860    2130-2273/com.android.calendar D/AlertService﹕ Scheduling next alarm with AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
05-11 15:31:29.863    2130-2273/com.android.calendar D/AlarmScheduler﹕ No events found starting within 1 week.
05-11 15:31:31.124    1218-1236/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{1985c099 u0 com.example.pallavi.project/.New t38 f}
05-11 15:31:33.302    1218-1816/system_process I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22885(1778KB) AllocSpace objects, 25(1739KB) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 443us total 19.555ms
05-11 15:31:33.314    1765-2379/com.google.android.gms I/iu.UploadsManager﹕ End new media; added: 0, uploading: 0, time: 52 ms
05-11 15:31:34.564    1765-2251/com.google.android.gms V/ConfigFetchTask﹕ ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1XXGxcq7BMFyB3VpnYqkuJ0zBLomkMGX-C8nW501WUsnb0lcC08LpquYUIsL-GGhixNWgrJLPvTVAw_4aO6pZJ-f0pws18TXBljF3PnOWeUMv_dmFylUQ4CZtISzUpjd3sHqllt34lBFjXKIeMI_haVO7k8ycBH0aKhbZ-7oKDK_0hcvD6unM9hoXvyaDf7wHyy3ZrNPoOOXkZuk9Ly00A-Wt8FbYNHg7DDJRdxoXJgHB6N2r6E_dCntd7koMlff1avPpuapg1sWuavKXB_DSp161P8SumBYofET4-62mJQZcAaLfo
05-11 15:31:34.566    1765-2251/com.google.android.gms I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
05-11 15:31:34.570    1765-2251/com.google.android.gms W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
05-11 15:31:34.865    1765-1765/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ fetch service done; releasing wakelock
05-11 15:31:34.866    1765-1765/com.google.android.gms I/ConfigFetchService﹕ stopping self
05-11 15:31:37.824    1218-1236/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{3483d1d4 u0 com.android.calendar/.alerts.InitAlarmsService}
05-11 15:31:39.915    1593-1593/com.google.process.gapps I/ConfigService﹕ onDestroy
05-11 15:31:42.245    1765-2105/com.google.android.gms I/CheckinService﹕ Done disabling old GoogleServicesFramework version
05-11 15:31:52.885    2130-2160/com.android.calendar D/InitAlarmsService﹕ Clearing and rescheduling alarms.
05-11 15:31:52.890    1218-1586/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 1503:com.android.printspooler/u0a42 (adj 15): empty #17
05-11 15:31:52.896    1218-1412/system_process W/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to open /acct/uid_10042/pid_1503/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
05-11 15:32:15.076    1218-1816/system_process I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@af8ca39com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$3@1aa1a87e
05-11 15:32:15.077    1218-1817/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 1684:com.android.music/u0a36 (adj 15): empty #17
05-11 15:32:15.085    1218-1402/system_process W/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to open /acct/uid_10036/pid_1684/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
05-11 15:33:25.507    1593-3249/com.google.process.gapps I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
05-11 15:33:25.513    1593-3249/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
05-11 15:33:26.236    1593-3249/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ no longer exists, so no auth token.
05-11 15:33:26.494    1593-3249/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
05-11 15:33:26.705    1593-3249/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader﹕ No account for auth token provided
05-11 15:33:26.947    1593-1602/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
            at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:478)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:668)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:795)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.b(SourceFile:764)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:667)
            at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:658)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:370)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:251)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.e.a(SourceFile:223)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.UploaderService.b(SourceFile:61)
            at com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader.UploaderService.a(SourceFile:35)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.ar.run(SourceFile:131)
05-11 15:36:20.289    1869-1869/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1869 SIG: 9
05-11 15:36:20.296    1218-1412/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1869 uid 10058
05-11 15:36:20.299    1218-1586/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.pallavi.project (pid 1869) has died
05-11 15:43:41.403    1218-1266/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{25575d45 VFED..CL ......ID 0,0-222,276 #0} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{2cfbec9a VFED..CL ......ID 270,0-492,276 #1} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{276d9cb VFED..CL ......ID 540,0-762,276 #2} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{f8c5a8 VFED..CL ......ID 810,0-1032,276 #3} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{3e1588c1 VFED..CL ......ID 0,290-222,566 #4} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{51c3866 VFED..CL ......ID 270,290-492,566 #5} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{b1747a7 VFED..CL ......ID 540,290-762,566 #6} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{22e89454 VFED..CL ......ID 810,290-1032,566 #7} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{730effd VFED..CL ......ID 0,580-222,856 #8} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{13a374f2 VFED..CL ......ID 270,580-492,856 #9} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{f66b743 VFED..CL ......ID 540,580-762,856 #a} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{1b64a1c0 VFED..CL ......ID 810,580-1032,856 #b} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.427    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{2da18ef9 VFED..CL ......ID 0,870-222,1146 #c} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{34efee3e VFED..CL ......ID 270,870-492,1146 #d} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{26b3849f VFED..CL ......ID 540,870-762,1146 #e} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{1ed219ec VFED..CL ......ID 810,870-1032,1146 #f} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{1be321b5 VFED..CL ......ID 0,1160-222,1436 #10} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{1af8b04a VFED..CL ......ID 270,1160-492,1436 #11} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{24d5cbbb VFED..CL ......ID 540,1160-762,1436 #12} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:41.428    1461-1461/com.android.launcher W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.launcher2.PagedViewIcon{20bce8d8 VFED..CL ......ID 810,1160-1032,1436 #13} during layout: running second layout pass
05-11 15:43:45.307    1218-1266/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-11 15:43:45.314    1218-1231/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.pallavi.project/.New (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0
05-11 15:43:45.345    1218-1232/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.pallavi.project for activity com.example.pallavi.project/.New: pid=7984 uid=10058 gids={50058, 9997} abi=x86
05-11 15:43:45.352    7984-7984/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-11 15:43:45.453    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
05-11 15:43:45.455    7984-7984/com.example.pallavi.project D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae1ef650, tid 7984
05-11 15:43:45.458    7984-7984/com.example.pallavi.project D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
05-11 15:43:45.492    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae1ef900, tid 7999
05-11 15:43:45.495    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 15:43:45.510    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-11 15:43:45.526    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-11 15:43:45.526    7984-7999/com.example.pallavi.project W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c32280, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-11 15:43:45.771    1218-1241/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.pallavi.project/.New: +437ms
05-11 15:43:46.593    1218-1266/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-11 15:43:46.599    7984-7984/com.example.pallavi.project D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-11 15:43:46.600    7984-7984/com.example.pallavi.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pallavi.project, PID: 7984
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onButtonClick(View) in the activity class com.example.pallavi.project.New for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'Bdisplay'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onButtonClick [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-11 15:43:46.602    1218-1502/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.pallavi.project/.New
05-11 15:43:46.607    1218-1502/system_process D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa2e2c750, tid 1502
05-11 15:43:46.609      920-920/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 920: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-11 15:43:46.668    1218-2023/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 15:43:46.681    1218-2023/system_process W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-11 15:43:46.681    1218-2023/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e306b80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-11 15:43:47.135    1218-1236/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{46ec2fd u0 com.example.pallavi.project/.New t39 f}
05-11 15:43:47.180    1461-1619/com.android.launcher W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-11 15:43:47.180    1461-1619/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb0a9dcc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-11 15:43:49.897    1218-1277/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=38_task.xml
05-11 15:43:49.897    1218-1277/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=38_task_thumbnail.png
05-11 15:43:57.526    1218-1236/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{46ec2fd u0 com.example.pallavi.project/.New t39 f}
05-11 15:44:00.036    1461-1619/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
05-11 15:44:09.049    1765-8185/com.google.android.gms I/EventLogService﹕ Aggregate from 1431337234018 (log), 1431337234018 (data)
05-11 15:48:46.671    7984-7984/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 7984 SIG: 9
05-11 15:48:46.678    1218-1412/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 7984 uid 10058
05-11 15:48:46.680    1218-1231/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.pallavi.project (pid 7984) has died
05-11 15:51:07.942    1218-1235/system_process I/UsageStatsService﹕ User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
```

Comment: I am unable to see the error

Comment: You never name a class "NEW"

Comment: you should include the stack trace from the logcat

Comment: where is the error??

Comment: When does the error occur? Also post the errorlog?

Comment: sorry, it says i am not allowed to post the error.......

Comment: the layout xml for `R.layout.activity_new` and `R.layout.activity_display`

Comment: post your xml files as well.

Comment: Pallavi please share error log.. Meanwhile you must read about good coding conventions see link http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/10/10-java-best-practices-to-name-variables-methods-classes-packages.html.. Good code is a virtue to read..

Comment: Freinds when i am running my app its displays my New.xml page when i click DISPLAY button it have to go to Display.xml but at that time it is producing error

Comment: In your `activity_new.xml` change button `onClick` value to `onbuttonClick`, your current value is `onButtonClick`

Comment: your logcat clearly says `Could not find a method onButtonClick(View)` in your activity

Comment: They are saying to post an image i need min of 10 points

Comment: Thank you....It worked when i changed onclick to onButtonClick and also in Work.java tooo.@JibranKhan,@Rustam

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
public void onbuttonClick(View v)
```

By

```
public void onButtonClick(View v)
```

Actually, you have defined

```
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" in your xml
```

And, you are using onbuttonClick() in your java thats why its giving you an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `onbuttonClick` to `onButtonClick` in you New.java

Answer (score 1):

You Stacktrace clearly says: No Such Method onButtonClick. So, what I assume is that You have added this in Your xml layout

```
      android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

But Your method inside the New class is called:

```
      public void onbuttonClick(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.Bdisplay)
    {

        Intent i= new Intent(New.this,Display.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }

}
```

So You have to change inside Your xml layout the attribute to:

```
        android:onClick="onbuttonClick"
```

or change in java class to

```
        public void onButtonClick(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.Bdisplay)
    {

        Intent i= new Intent(New.this,Display.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

first you casting your button in oncreate method. and also implements onclicklistener and also do like

```
button_name.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Thanks